# Skype Meta Tag Support IE8/7

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, meta-tags, meta, skype

I cannot see any information about it, but does anyone know the support of:

`<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />`

in websites to turn off the Skype formatting of telephone numbers. This is located in my website, but I have noticed that the formatting still appears in IE8. This appears both if it is in IE7 compatibility mode and in default IE8 mode.

Has Skype dropped the support for this tag? (Doubt this is true as it doesn't appear in Chrome)
Is there a different format of Meta Tag for IE8/7? 
Does this tag just not work in IE8/7?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a great description of what that meta tag does [here](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions):

> Prevents the Skype browser extension from automatically seeking
>   through the page and replacing telephone numbers (or any number the
>   program's algorithm thinks is a telephone number) with its own custom
>   presentation that allows direct invocation of the Skype program to
>   call the telephone number.

I found this comment by [robocat](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/47173/robocat) on a [Stack Exchange answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67056/63326) that appears to confirm it works as of August 2015:

> Aug 2015: I just tested that inserting  into your page head still
>   disables the Skype phone number highlighting. I installed Skype Click
>   To Call plug-in and enabled it in IE11. A test webpage with phone
>   numbers in it, has the tags modified by the window.SkypeClick2Call
>   object (which is inserted into the page by the plug-in). Added the
>   meta tag into the test page head and the phone numbers are no longer
>   modified (neither is the window.SkypeClick2Call object injected).